# trying to display json data with angularjs ng-repeat not working

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've seen so many ways to do this, but most are pretty old and I want to make sure I'm doing this correctly. Right now, the way I'm using isn't working and I feel like I'm missing something.

I'm getting the JSON back fine, I just need to get it to display in a table after I click the button.

Here is the JSON. This is how I'm going to get it from our server, I can't add any "var JSON =" or add any scope like "$scope.carrier" to the data, unless there's a way to add it after I've fetched the data.

```
{
    "carrier": 
    [
        {
        "entity": "carrier",
        "id": 1,
        "parentEntity": "ORMS",
        "value": "Medica"
    }, {
        "entity": "carrier",
        "id": 2,
        "parentEntity": "ORMS",
        "value": "UHG"
    }, {
        "entity": "carrier",
        "id": 3,
        "parentEntity": "ORMS",
        "value": "Optum"
    }, {
        "entity": "carrier",
        "id": 4,
        "parentEntity": "ORMS",
        "value": "Insight"
    }, {
        "entity": "carrier",
        "id": 5,
        "parentEntity": "ORMS",
        "value": "Insight"
    }
    ]
}
```

Here is the app.js file to bring back the JSON data:

```
var app = angular.module('myTestApp', []);

app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
var url = 'test.json';
  $scope.clickButton = function() {
    $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
  }
}]);
```

And then of course the HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
             <button type=button class="btn btn-primary load" ng-click="clickButton()">Click!</button>
         <table class="">
             <tbody ng-repeat="carrier in carriers">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h3 class="">{{ module.entity }}</h3>
                        <h3 class="">{{ module.id }}</h3>
                        <h3 class="">{{ module.parentEntity }}</h3>
                        <h3 class="">{{ module.value }}</h3>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

I'm also wondering if I can use the ng-grid to put this in a table. I know they just upgraded it to ui grid so I'm not sure if this is still a feasible approach.

Also, I'm not getting errors, the data just won't display in the table right now. All I know is its returning the data properly, just not displaying in the table.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps try changing `module.___` to `carrier.___`. Your `ng-repeat` block is binding each individual item of the list to a context called `carrier`.

Comment: you don't do anything with the incoming data beside logging it, so it does what you told it (nothing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your plunker seems like you need to:

- add angular script
- wire the app and the controller
- your variable in the repeater is wrong, I change it

take a look to this fixed plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/TAjnUCMOBxQTC6lNJL8j?p=preview

```
 $scope.clickButton = function() {
     $http.get(url).success(function(returnValue) {
         alert(JSON.stringify(returnValue.carrier));
         $scope.carriers = returnValue.carrier;  
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You never assign the value of the returned array to `$scope.carriers`.

At the line where you say `console.log(data);` add this:

```
$scope.carriers = data.data;
```

Here is the updated `clickButton` function (with a variable name change to reduce confusion):

```
$scope.clickButton = function() {
  $http.get(url).success(function(returnValue) {
    $scope.carriers = returnValue.data;
  });
};
```

Comment: I updated the code. Still no errors, but the data still isn't being displayed. Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ydJPmdCm5zVN58wPYuYY)

Comment: Your Plunker is missing a lot...you never load Angular itself, you never mention the app in your HTML, you never mention your controller in your HTML, etc. I'll try to figure out what all you are missing/have wrong...but in the meantime, please review some tutorials and the docs again

Comment: @jack.the.ripper beat me to it...he fixed up your omissions from the plunker

Comment: jack and @Kabb5 Thanks for both of your help! I had been changing the code so frequently, I didn't realize I deleted initializing the app (ng-app = "myTestApp") on the container. Jack's code worked, and yeah, I have to go back and review the docs again.